# pdf as an email attachment in iOS device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf-generation, email-attachments

I would like to attach pdf created as an email attachment. I used following tutorial to create pdf on iOS device.

The downloaded pdf can be viewed at this path: 
/Users/”Username”/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/”Your App Directory”.

I have not tried running this on ios device but I need to attach it as an email.

Link for tutorial is : 
http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/

Any suggestion.

Comment: I dunno @PengOne.  It looks like a declaration of achievement ("I created a PDF!").  Maybe he wants somebody to tell him how to use `MFMessageComposeViewController`??

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation and trying to implement it yourself before you ask a question. Here are the docs:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html Try it, if you have errors come back and tell us what the errors are and then we can try to help you.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Create a `MFMailComposeViewController` and call `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`. The data will be the PDF you created. The mimeType will be `application/pdf`. And the fileName will be the name of the file in the email attachment. The code might look like something below:

From the tutorial you'll need to render your PDF into a NSMutableData object:

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, bounds, nil);
```

Then at some point in the future you'll need to pass that pdfData to the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *vc = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[vc setSubject:@"my pdf"];
[vc addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"SomeFile.pdf"];
```

Comment: Thanks Evan for the code snippet.

Comment: I am still lacking Voteup reputation by 2 points. :( ... Anyways, My code is working now. Thanks a ton :D

Comment: How to set properties to add security so that no one can edit and also print/copy the attachment. I am trying something like this:   // this one is for copying  CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying, kCFBooleanFalse);
        CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting, kCFBooleanFalse);   I looked in the apple's document but can't find the method for protection for editing. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html                Even my above two methods are not working.

Comment: Here is d correct code snippet:                       CFMutableDictionaryRef myDictionary = NULL;
        
          
myDictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0,
                                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
        
        
        
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying, kCFBooleanFalse);
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting, kCFBooleanFalse);

Comment: Hi guys, when the email composer modal view appears, it is VERY SLOW because it's previewing the pdf file. Any way to have it NOT preview the pdf file?

Answer (score 2):

See the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for `MFMailComposeViewController`. Specifically, you're looking for the `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` method. That should get you going.

Comment: I think I was not clear about my question. sorry abt that. 
I am not sure about the path to attach pdf to email. In the sample code
on developers forum: 

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    
    Here the full path was not required as the attachment was added to the project itself. 
    Now when i am creating pdf on the device itself, How should I give path for sending?

Comment: Since that tutorial is saving the PDF to the file system, you just pass in the same path to `dataWithContentsOfFile:` that you passed into `generatePdfWithFilePath:`. Make sense?

Comment: How to set properties to add security so that no one can edit and also print/copy the attachment. I am trying something like this:   // this one is for copying  CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying, kCFBooleanFalse);
        CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting, kCFBooleanFalse);   I looked in the apple's document but can't find the method for protection for editing. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html                Even my above two methods are not working.

Comment: CFMutableDictionaryRef myDictionary = NULL;
        
          
myDictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0,
                                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
        
        
        
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying, kCFBooleanFalse);
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting, kCFBooleanFalse);

Comment: You'll need to start a new question for that issue.

Comment: Alright. I asked as a new thread. Thanks.