# how to attach files for mailing in xcode

Tags: iphone, email-attachments

I have a mailcomposer in which i have attached a file through coding(hard-coded)..

I need to have a button so that When i press the button.It should ask which file to attach...

My code is shown below in which i am attaching the file hordcoded...

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Mehmood.jpg"];
NSData *imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1);
[composer addAttachmentData:imgData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Mehmood.jpg"];
```

Even I need to attach any file which i  am selecting after button click(not the specific one like `png/jpeg`)...

Please help...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you.

[Where's the iPhone MIME type database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439020/wheres-the-iphone-mime-type-database/2439038#2439038)

Comment: Sorry,I didnot understand... I need to select a file from my ipad/iphone whether it be from phone or it's memory card of phone(if present).... How to add button for composing mail in the mfMailComposerViewController for selecting the attachment...

Comment: @vishaldharmawat its a link dude chek this link . it shows that code return myme type. maybe that would help u.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824647/send-an-iphone-attachment-through-email-programmatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846338/pdf-as-an-email-attachment-in-ios-device

Comment: Sorry...but tell me can we add button for selecting attachment in mailcomposer..like we get button for attaching file in gmail...If yes,,then how?..

Comment: @vishaldharmawat https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @vishaldharmawat this link tell you that u cant customize mailcomposer . so i thnk you cant add button.

Comment: then Chinttu how can i add attachment depending upon my choice if not hardcoded...

Comment: @vishaldharmawat i gave you that link maybe it will return mime type. i didnt use but i just search for you. so u have to just pass file name there and it will return mime type. try it maybe it will help you. not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really modify the standard mail composer window to add your own buttons. You should ask the user what they want to attach before presenting the mail composer.