# Attaching a pdf file in an email in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, sendmail, email-attachments

I have made a pdf file and I am trying to attach it with the email but the file doesn't get attached infact the file name isn't what, what it is suppose to be. Following is my code

```
- (IBAction)btnAttachPDF:(id)sender {


if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailer setSubject:@"video"];

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *fileName;
    fileName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", lblName.text];
```

lblName.text suppose to returns me the file name which i have entered but it is just .pdf but if I give it a hardcoded value it does stores the name of the file lets say I gave it a name @"rio.pdf" but later on the file doesn't get attached.

```
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSMutableData *myPdfData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
    [mailer addAttachmentData:myPdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fileName];


    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];




}



else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                    message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [pdf as an email attachment in iOS device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846338/pdf-as-an-email-attachment-in-ios-device)

Comment: Have you linked your "lblName" label in xib properly, looks like it is null. Can you try logging NSLog(@"%@", lblName);

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya better open the link he has given in the question, it doesn't even exists :/

Comment: Is it giving you proper name? and where you setting value for this??

Comment: @rishi I have done it actually the path returned by NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains wasn't complete. That was causing this problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Then you can post that as an answer yourself, accept that and close the question.

Comment: @rishi Would you mind rating the answer? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the path returned by NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains isn't the exact one. The last component it was returning was /Documents whereas, the files were being saved in /Documents/temp/filename.pdf